# AWS - Terraform create multiple ALB target groups with different IP targets for each

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create multiple AWS ALB target groups with different set of IP targets for each target groups.

I have variables defined as below.

```
variable "target_group_names" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["tg1", "tg2", "tg3", "tg4"]
}

variable "target_ips" {
  type = list(list(string))
  default = [
    ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"],
    ["10.0.1.1", "10.0.1.2", "10.0.1.3"],
    ["10.0.2.1", "10.0.2.2"],
    ["10.0.3.1", "10.0.3.2"]
  ]
}
```

I was able to create all the target groups without any issues using below.

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_groups" {
  count       = length(var.target_group_names)
  name        = var.target_group_names[count.index]
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = var.aws_vpc_id
}
```

now I'm trying to add different IP targets to these individual target groups.

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "tg_attachment" {
  count             = length(var.target_group_names)
  target_group_arn  = aws_lb_target_group.target_groups[count.index].arn
  target_id         = var.target_ips[count.index]
  port              = 80
  availability_zone = "all"
}
```

This gives me below error which is a valid one since for the target_id I'm passing a list above.

"Inappropriate value for attribute "target_id": string required."

I'm trying to find a way to create multiple target groups and then assign different sets of IPs to each target group without coding resource blocks for each. I'm new to Terraform so any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

I tried few combinations with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had the chance to try the solution, but I would give a try to something like this by first rethinking the group variables.

```
variable "target_group_names" {
  type    = map(set(string))
  default = {
    "tg1": ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"], 
    "tg2": ["10.0.1.1", "10.0.1.2", "10.0.1.3"], 
    "tg3": ["10.0.2.1", "10.0.2.2"], 
    "tg4": ["10.0.3.1", "10.0.3.2"]
  }
}
```

Then to make things more readable extract groups in a local variable.

```
locals {
  target_groups = [
    for name, ips in var.target_group_names : {
      name = name
      ips  = ips
    }
  ]
}
```

at this point you should be able to iterate in both resources:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_groups" {
  for_each = { for idx, tg in local.target_groups : idx => tg }
  name     = each.value.name
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = var.aws_vpc_id
}


resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "tg_attachment" {
  for_each = {
    for idx, tg in aws_lb_target_group.target_groups : idx => tg
  }
  target_group_arn = tg.arn
  target_id        = each.key
  # other configuration...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @leonardo. I've tried above solution and getting below error from the target group attachment section.

Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│ 
│   on target_groups.tf line 36, in resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "tg_attachment":
│   36:   target_group_arn  = tg.arn
│ 
│ A managed resource "tg" "arn" has not been declared in the root module.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by changing the target_group_arn as below.

target_group_arn  = each.value.arn

This now creates the target groups. But the assignment still fails with below error.

registering targets with target group: ValidationError: The IP address '2' is not a valid IPv4 address